# Android gallery horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I have a gallery with images and when scroll horizontally, multiple images are scrolled instead of one.

Below is part of my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(resourceid, null);
    }
    synchronized (view) {
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtCaption);
        ImageList item = getItem(position);

        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ivImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        
        try {
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(item.imageUrl));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works perfectly.

PS: You need to extends a Gallery.

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    int kEvent =
            e1.getX() < e2.getX() ? KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT : KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
    onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for that you have create custom gallery you can refer the example [here](http://www.zumodrive.com/files?key=5SBbYzk0Mj#item=170533562)

to slow down fast navigation of your gallery try below code

```
yourGallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
```

Comment: thanks for the info but i already have done that but it still the same and could show some sample code pls

Comment: i had given the link dear just modifying that